# How to access the getter in provider in flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have assigned the value from changeNotifierproxyProvider to the Company provider. I have to access the value from the Company class provider to screen widget.

My code is

Company.dart

```
class Company with ChangeNotifier{
final bool _companyCreated;

Company(this._companyCreated);

get isCompanyCreated{
return _companyCreated;
}
```

ProducerSignUpScreen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:scopemobileapp/providers/company.dart';

class ProducerSignUpScreen extends StatefulWidget {
static const routeName = '/producer-signup';

}

@override
_ProducerSignUpScreenState createState() => _ProducerSignUpScreenState();
}

class _ProducerSignUpScreenState extends State<ProducerSignUpScreen> {
**bool companycreated = Company.isCompanyCreated();**
}
```

i want to call the isCompanyCreated from the producer sign up screen and assign the value to variable companyCreated

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use `Provider.of<Company>(context);` in your `build` method so you can have access to an instance of `Company` class. Also, don't forget to provide `Company` class in the nearest parent of the children that use `Provider.of(context)` so `InheritedWidget` can access the instance you want to use.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context){
      final company = Provider.of<Company>(context);
      bool companycreated = company.isCompanyCreated;
      return .....
```

}